# Javascript Event delegation vs Multiple Events Listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Greetings I have a table with multiple lines
and every line has multiple different functionality buttons.
(delete , edit ,load details of Row)

line1       ButtonEdit,ButtonDelete,ButtonLoadsomething
.
.
.
line n

I am almost sure that for a big table more than 1000 lines (=having  1000 event listeners) memory wise it make sense to add only on click event listener to my table and check if the event.target has a specified class name.
to act appropriate.

I want to ask if it is valuable to add event listener for every different button category.
Meaning instead of multiple click listeners
on page I could use just one and check with if statements and running the appropriate functionality afterwards .

To sum up,where would you put your button listener and why?
(3000 event listeners, 3 event listeners or 1) what is faster, what is more maintainable?
How would you handle the click event if not with if statement